# Is there a high-level framework from which all known search and optimization algorithms can be derived?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, search

The fields of applied math and computer science are inundated with optimization algorithms, variations on those optimization algorithms, and variations on those variations.

I'm mainly talking about heuristic algorithms such as evolutionary search, particle swarm, simulated annealing, and their many, many variants.

Is there some high level grammar that can describe all these algorithms and, conceivably, any possible future search algorithm such that it would be very hard to create an optimization method that can't be derived from this framework?

Comment: Does Python count as high-level?  Does English count as high-level?